# css color and image color

Tags: css, background-color

I have a question. Are css color(#xxxxxx) and image color be same?

For example the css is

```
#div1 { 
    background-color: #cf5654;
}

#div2 {
    background-image: url('1.png');
}
```

and the images color is `#cf5654`. Will it be same in any screen?

Comment: Colors with the same colorcode are always the same. It really depends on what color your image is.

Comment: Why would you want to use an image to do a simple colored background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be same in any screen?

**No.**

Images can contain color profiles, but they don't have to.

Not all browsers respect color profiles. And not all browsers are color managed.

Monitors can be properly calibrated or not.

On a properly color managed and calibrated system then the image *should* appear the same as the hex color. However, if a browser/system is not color managed, or poorly calibrated, then no, the image will most likely not be the same as the hex color. In fact, it is possible in some scenarios to have drastically differing appearances between the image and the hex.

Answer (score 1):

good one, but you might have a separate case when talking about cross-browsing rendering HEX.

might be worth giving it a read here: http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

so in this case, my answer is no.

Comment: Thanks,I will notice these mistakes in future

Answer (score 0):

It depends on image compression, then image could have little border around "manually created png". 
But, generally, no. It will be same at any screen